# Ignore duplicate rows while adding to database with Blaze's Odo

Tags: postgresql, pandas, psycopg2, blaze

How can I ignore duplicate rows while storing a dataframe in a postgres DB with Blaze's [Odo](http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/)?

For example, I store the first 3 rows like this:

```
>>> odo(df[:3], 'postgresql:///my_db::my_table')
```

**`my_table`** has a column ***ID*** as a primary key. If I add a few more but this time *including the previous last row*, I want to skip that row and add others instead of getting that `IntegrityError`.

```
>>> odo(df[2:5], 'postgresql:///my_db::my_table')

    IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint  ...
```

How can I do that? Loading `ID` values from DB and checking for duplicates seems expensive to me if the DB has millions of rows. Is there any better alternative?
Something like this:

```
INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE
```

Blaze: 0.8.3, Postgres: 9.4.4, Psycopg2: 2.6.1

Comment: Can you not drop the dups before writing to db? `df.drop_duplicates()` you can optionally pass your ID column `df.drop_duplicates('ID')`, it unclear what you're asking specifically, are you wanting to insert all rows and ensire `ID` is unique or you actually want to drop duplicate rows?

Comment: Yeah, but even after that I can't know whether some of these unique IDs  already exist in the DB.

Comment: You could read the IDs back from the DB and the filter these out

Comment: @EdChum I updated my post...

Answer (score 1):

The data model for `odo` only supports appending, not merging. You'll need to either remove duplicates before passing it through `odo`, or use the database to remove the duplicates. Try adding an auto-increment field, and set it as the primary key. This will fix your `IntegrityError` problems on insertion, and you can remove the duplicates after that.